# Apache configuration

Tags: apache2, php, webserver

I am new to Ubuntu , I am configuring Apache to read  root document  from my home directory sites directory

I edited the (default) file under /**etc/apache2/available-sites** 
to read from **/home/username**

When I restart Apache it reads from my home directory to be it's default page

What I am trying to accessing Apache localhost by making users 
such as `http://localhost/~user1/`

How I can do this ?

Comment: Which Apache version are you using? `apache2 -v`

Comment: Server version: Apache/2.2.22

Comment: I had assumed you were using Apache 2.4 in my answer. I edited it so my solution works with Apache 2.2

Comment: @Dan i did all the instruction but still not working , can i find a way to debug what is the error ?   all i get The requested URL /~/user1/index.html was not found on this server.

Comment: The URL should be /~user1/index.html not /~/user1/index.html. There shouldn't be a / after the `~` character

Comment: Finally it works , Thanks for Your effort @Dan

Answer (score 3):

This functionality is available by enabling the Apache [`userdir`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_userdir.html#userdir) module with:

```
sudo a2enmod userdir
```

Your next step is to configure how you want Apache to handle the URIs.

Some examples:

- If you want the URL `http://localhost/~user1/site1` to load from the `/home/user1/site1` directory, you need to use

  ```
  UserDir ./
  ```
- If you want the URL `http://localhost/~user1/site1` to load from the `/home/user1/sites/site1` directory, you need to use

  ```
  UserDir sites
  ```

To add the configuration, and assuming you are using Apache 2.2, create the following file  `/etc/apache2/conf.d/userdir.conf` and add the following to it:

```
# This is just a safety measure to make sure the root user isn't used.
UserDir disabled root

# Swap the following line with whatever configuration you require.
UserDir sites

# If you chose "UserDir ./" instead of "UserDir sites",
# remove the "sites/" part in the next line
<Directory /home/*/sites/>
    Order allow, deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Once you're done, you will need to restart Apache:

```
sudo apache2ctl restart
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define `virtualhost` with different `servername` and `document root` for each people. But you should edit `/etc/hosts` for each user .
For example :

`Virtualhost *:80 
Servername  : person 1
Document root : /home/person1`

And also you can define `home` directory as `document root` and each user can find his/her directory.

**Notice** that you should give `www-data` owner ship on their home and permission to do their staff.

**PS** : why you don't don't try `vsftpd` for your scenario ?! That will be better.

Comment: How can `vsftpd` help in this case? `vsftpd` is an ftp server.

Comment: As I understood from what you asked you wanna setup  remote server each user can access his own file ( that's what I though ! )

Comment: I'm not the one who asked,  but the OP is asking how to make a URL like `http://localhost/~username` point directly to the sites directory in that user's home dir, i.e. `/home/username/sites`.

Comment: I didn't notice that you wanna something like you said.

Comment: @eng_ahmed The file doesn't exist, you need to create it yourself.

Comment: Actually i would like to use the functionality userdir , but i used configuration i didn't find this path /etc/apache2/conf-available/userdir.conf , i found userdir.conf in /etc/apache2/mod-enable/userdir.conf .  are the files the same and also  a2enconf don't work  @Dan

Comment: ( conf-available ) directory is not available create it also ?

Comment: Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.   i got this error 

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80